# Eclipse Neon 64-bit is not launching in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse-jee-neon-1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz but I'm unable to launch it. It's showing the below error.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1.v20160907-1200/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 588012
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The default java version in 14.04 is java 7, eclipse neon requires java8 which you will need to download and install next to your existing java version.